# Units of Measurement Part II — Hours, Minutes and Seconds

Tags: punctuation

Again, I prefer the brevity and concision of these examples.

It was a 2hr 3min 4sec marathon.
(Is this correct if we opted to abbreviate?) The Guardian and the BBC use this so I'm assuming it's okay.

They also use both versions below:
1. The marathon lasted 2hrs 3mins 4secs.
2. The marathon lasted 2hr 3min 4sec. (Which would you pick, 1 or 2?)

Comment: Probably the second.

Answer (score 3):

That's maybe a bit too far down the road, but the brochure on the International System of Units (SI) states that:

> Unit symbols are mathematical entities and not abbreviations. Therefore, they are not 
>   followed by a period except at the end of a sentence, and one must neither use the 
>   plural nor mix unit symbols and unit names within one expression, since names are 
>   not mathematical entities.

And further

> In any one expression, only one unit is used. An exception to this rule is in expressing
>   the values of time and of plane angles using non-SI units.

Thus, regarding the rules of SI **The marathon lasted 2hr 3min 4sec.** is correct.

[The brochure](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/)